# How to put mat-table inside mat-expansion in angular10

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to do a list of users and when clicking on the user the corresponding addresses table can be expanded. But the thing is that when I clicked on it it shows blank. Does anyone konw what's the problem?

Here is the reproduce link:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-8ciy8z?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

This is the problem screenshot:

[image: table contents are not displayed]

Answer (score 1):

Hi you forgot a few things like `displayedColumns` property.
You forgot to put  `matColumnDef` in the `ng-container`.
You insert `mat-sort-header` without using it right.

Here is a quick fixed [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-ljkwbg?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem. I'm new to material. Thank you very much!